# Remove all character after nth underscore in Teradata sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column with values as xxx_xxxx_xxxy_zzzz something like this .I need to remove all characters after nth or suppose 3rd underscore from given values of the column and use remaining string in join condition ?

Your help would be much appeciated .

Thanks ,
Atul

Comment: Hi, please provided some information, like actual data table column and excepted output and what you're actualy trying.

Comment: Hi Pascal , Suppose I have data value as atul_bajpayee_india in column X of a table and I have to join it with Y cloumn of another table which has data value as atul_bajpayee .For join to happen on X=Y I have to remove all value after 3rd underscore including underscore then only data value would be same .Inshort both coluumn have same values upto second underscore and value after 3rd underscore is more defining and diffrent which is not required and is causing issue in join .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTR('atul_bajpayee_india',1,REGEXP_INSTR('atul_bajpayee_india', '_', 1, 2, 0, 'c')-1);
```

This will user REGEXP_INSTR to find in this case the second underscore as the fourth argument in REGEXP_INSTR. This returns the position in the string, that can then be used to get the substring. -1 doesnt include the second underscore.

if you were to use the initial example 'xxx_xxxx_xxxy_zzzz'and wanted to remove everything after the 3rd underscore it would be

```
SELECT SUBSTR('xxx_xxxx_xxxy_zzzz',1,REGEXP_INSTR('xxx_xxxx_xxxy_zzzz', '_', 1, 3, 0, 'c')-1);
```

Some good further reading here 
http://www.teradatawiki.net/2014/05/regular-expression-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSTR to find the `nth` occurance of a search string:

```
Substr(col, 1, Instr(col, '_', 1, 3)-1)
```

Edit:

A better way uses REGEXP_SUBSTR:

```
RegExp_Substr(col, '[^_]+(_[^_]+){0,n-1}')
```

E.g. remove everything after the 3rd underscore:

```
RegExp_Substr('xxx_xxxx_xxxy_zzzz', '[^_]+(_[^_]+){0,2}')
```

This also works if there are less than *n* underscores

Comment: the above wont work, instr requires 4 arguments.
INSTR(source_string, search_string,position, occurance)
SUBSTR(col,1,INSTR(col,'_',1,n)-1) [see above answer]
-1 is required to no include the nth underscore that is being looked for

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution might be to use this:

```
select STRTOK( 'xxx_xxxx_xxxy_zzzz', '_', 4);
```

This would give you the "zzzz" token.

Comment: But it should return `xxx_xxxx_xxxy` :-)

Comment: The original request was: "I need to remove all characters after nth or suppose 3rd underscore from given values of the column and use remaining string" - so it'll do just that, no?